# Whether JavascriptChannels work in web version the webview plugin flutter?

Tags: flutter, webview, flutter-web

I want to use `WebView` widget in web application. I use `webview_flutter_web`, but when I run the application, messages to my `JavascriptChannel` don't come, although on mobile platforms everything works fine, and I didn't find anything in the documentation about this issue. Can someone help me figure this out? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to readme:

```
It is currently severely limited and doesn't implement most of the available functionality. The following functionality is currently available:

loadUrl (Without headers)
requestUrl
loadHTMLString (Without baseUrl)
Setting the initialUrl through CreationParams.
Nothing else is currently supported.
```

webview_flutter_web does not support JavascriptChannels yet.